# How can I split a dictionary into train and test set Python where values of each item is 99*160 sized list of numeric values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, split, deep-learning

I have 3222 .wav data structured as below as a dict output :

```
final = 
        {'item1.wav':Numpy array(99*160), 'item2.wav':Numpay array(99*160), ... ,'item3222.wav':Numpy 
        array(99*160)}
```

My question is how can I split this type of data into train and test in a way that 20% of 3222 items place in the test set?